# Unsure why my endpoint URL is throwing a 404 error upon making a post request

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I've been facing this issue for a few days - I'm not sure why I'm getting a `404` error even though my endpoint URL is correct.  I know it's correct because I've even verified through via the Network tab.  I'm testing via Postman and the API's working fine but some reason, the endpoint just can't be found.

My guess is that I probably need to include some additional code in my `api.php` file to make sure the URL can be properly read when making post request? Or maybe it's something in my `RegisterController`  But I'm not entirely sure.

Upon submitting the form I get a `405` error that says: `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.` which makes no sense because it's clearly a post request.

I've tried too many ways to list here in an attempt to rectify this but to no avail.  Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try to do to fix this?

Here's my react.js file

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import '../../../sass/LoginSignUp/LoginSignUp.scss'
import axios from 'axios';

const LoginSignUp = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");

const handleSubmit = () => {
    let data = {
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'confirmPassword': confirmPassword
    }

    let headers = {
        Accept: 'application/json'
    }

    axios.post('http://website.test/api/register', data, {headers})
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

return (
    <div className="section">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row full-height justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-12 text-center align-self-center py-5">
                    <div className="section pb-5 pt-5 pt-sm-2 text-center">
                        <h6 className="mb-0 pb-3"><span>Log In </span><span>Sign Up</span></h6>
                        <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="reg-log" name="reg-log"/>
                        <label htmlFor="reg-log"></label>
                        <div className="card-3d-wrap mx-auto">
                            <div className="card-3d-wrapper">
                               


                                <form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <div className="card-back">
                                        <div className="center-wrap">
                                            <div className="section text-center">
                                                <h4 className="mb-4 pb-3">Sign Up</h4>
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" name="logname"
                                                           className="form-style"
                                                           placeholder="Username"
                                                           id="userName"
                                                           autoComplete="none"
                                                           onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                    <i className="input-icon uil uil-user"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                    <input type="email" name="logemail"
                                                           className="form-style"
                                                           placeholder="Your Email"
                                                           id="logemail"
                                                           autoComplete="none"
                                                           onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                    <i className="input-icon uil uil-at"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                    <input type="password" name="logpass"
                                                           className="form-style"
                                                           placeholder="Your Password"
                                                           id="logpass"
                                                           autoComplete="none"
                                                           onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                    <i className="input-icon uil uil-lock-alt"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                    <input type="password" name="logpass"
                                                           className="form-style"
                                                           placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                                           id="logpass"
                                                           autoComplete="none"
                                                           onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                    <i className="input-icon uil uil-lock-alt"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <button className="btn mt-4">Submit</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default LoginSignUp;
```

Here's my RegisterController:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());
    }

    $userId = 'u-' . Str::uuid()->toString();
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
    $input['UserID'] = $userId;
    $user = User::create($input);
    $input['name'] = $user->name;
    $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;

    return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User registered successfully.');
}
```

Here's complete api.php:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\API\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\PhotosController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('login', [RegisterController::class, 'login']);

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
    Route::resource('photos', PhotosController::class);
});
```

Comment: Does your register route show up in `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: @Peppermintology yes, it does.

Comment: Try clearing your routes cache `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @Peppermintology tried that already, still getting the same result :(

Comment: There must be a URL mismatch then, check your browsers developer tools network tab and inspect the request.

Comment: @Peppermintology I've already mentioned I did that in my post :).

Comment: @sp92.try removing accept header and add 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: @sp92.one more doubt i have is are you setting any configuration of axios globally

Comment: @JohnLobo I just tried that, it didn't work :(

Comment: @sp92.looks strange  issue

Comment: can you post complete api.php file

Comment: @JohnLobo I've just posted the complete `api.php` file in my original post.

Comment: @sp92.looks good .once try php artisan route:clear then php artisan route:cache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233100/discussion-between-sp92-and-john-lobo).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle cors request

You can install this package

https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

To generate config file run following command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"
```

and then update
in config/cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

To allow CORS for all your routes, add the HandleCors middleware at the top of the `$middleware` property of `app/Http/Kernel.php class`:

```
protected $middleware = [
  \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    // ...
];
```