# Why's my POST request getting cancelled upon form submission?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I'm using a Laravel backend and React.js frontend.  My POST request works totally fine in Postman but...

Why would my Axios `POST` request in the browser throw me a status of `Cancelled`?  I'm not getting a `404` error (which I guess is a good sign, I think - correct me if I'm wrong).  Could this be a `CORS` issue?  I have `Fruitcake` setup so I'm handling the `CORS` scenario.  I'm just very confused on what to do.

If I add `method="POST"` to my `<form>`, and make a POST request (form submission) - I get a `404` error as well as `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.` when it's clearly a `POST` request.

I'm very confused, has anyone ever faced something like this before?

**Note:** My project's hosted on Vagrant (Homestead) with the typical `192.168.10.10` local IP address. Not sure this has something to do with it but just putting it out there.  Again, my `POST` request works fine in Postman.

I appreciate the guidance/help in advance.

Here's my React.js file:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const LoginSignUp = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        let data = {
            'name': name,
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'confirmPassword': confirmPassword
        };

        axios.post('http://project.test/api/register', data)
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="section">
                                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                        <div className="card-back">
                                            <div className="center-wrap">
                                                <div className="section text-center">
                                                    <h4 className="mb-4 pb-3">Sign Up</h4>
                                                    <div className="form-group">
                                                        <input type="text" name="logname"
                                                               className="form-style"
                                                               placeholder="Username"
                                                               id="userName"
                                                               autoComplete="none"
                                                               onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                                                        />
                                                        <i className="input-icon uil uil-user"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                        <input type="email" name="logemail"
                                                               className="form-style"
                                                               placeholder="Your Email"
                                                               id="logemail"
                                                               autoComplete="none"
                                                               onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                                        />
                                                        <i className="input-icon uil uil-at"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                        <input type="password" name="logpass"
                                                               className="form-style"
                                                               placeholder="Your Password"
                                                               id="logpass"
                                                               autoComplete="none"
                                                               onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                                                        />
                                                        <i className="input-icon uil uil-lock-alt"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                        <input type="password" name="logpassconfirm"
                                                               className="form-style"
                                                               placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                                               id="logpass"
                                                               autoComplete="none"
                                                               onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
                                                        />
                                                        <i className="input-icon uil uil-lock-alt"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <button className="btn mt-4">Submit</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
        </div>
    );
}


export default LoginSignUp;
```

Here's my `Kernel.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
            \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

Register controller:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());
    }

    $userId = 'u-' . Str::uuid()->toString();
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
    $input['UserID'] = $userId;
    $user = User::create($input);
    $input['name'] = $user->name;
    $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;

    return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User registered successfully.');
}
```

Here's my api.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\API\RegisterController;

Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
```

Comment: previous issue caused post for ref:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67763083/unsure-why-my-endpoint-url-is-throwing-a-404-error-upon-making-a-post-request

Comment: @JohnLobo ty! :)

Comment: can you create sandbox env to check error

Comment: @JohnLobo do you mean creating an env to simulate the entire project?  How would I be able to do that?

Comment: .reactjs simulator .like you  created for previous post

Comment: @JohnLobo https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-gagarin-4xdi1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: can you change APP_URI= to your actual url and run php artisan config:clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233150/discussion-between-sp92-and-john-lobo).